# How to use complex objects as clipping masks in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I am trying to make a clipping mask using a gold foil background and a mandala. When I try to make the clipping mask it says "*The top object is very complex, and may fail the document to print or preview if used as a mask. Do you want to make it a mask anyway?*". I click yes, and both objects dissappear. Could you help me on how to create clipping masks with complex objects?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a screenprint with the shape? We are visual people here, and they help understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The mask must be a path or a compound path and must be the top object, these are the rules.

See it at the properties bar, left top position.

If it says is an object or a group, make sure to ungroup it or make it a compound path using:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>  .