# How do I make an object fill transparent without showing background objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is what I have currently:

[image]

I am trying to acheive something like this but I would like the goblin at the front to be transparent not filled white

[image]

The front goblin was drawn with the pen tool and then tweaked with the path width tool, and finally converted to a live paint group.

I am new to illustrator so have no idea how I would go about this.

I relise this question was posted here ([How do I make an object fill transparent without showing objects below in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70404/how-do-i-make-an-object-fill-transparent-without-showing-objects-below-in-illust)) but that dosent work for me as I get an error when creating the clipping mask.

Comment: You can do this yes. Use a knockout group

Comment: You could merely **fill** some shapes with *white*.

Comment: You mentioned an error that you get, can you specify what it is?

Comment: The clipping mask rules: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99481/how-to-use-complex-objects-as-clipping-masks-in-illustrator

Answer (score 2):

Use an **opacity mask** instead.

Copy the big guy  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd> .

Paint it 100% black (0,0,0).

Group the small guys.

Select all and make an Opacity Mask.

Paste the copied guy.

See the image below:

[image]